# Bounded or unbounded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the operator $A\colon\ell^2\to\ell^2$ defined by $Au=(ku_k)$. Normally, this is not well-defined, since $(1/k)_{k=1}^\infty\in\ell^2$ but $A(1/k)=(1,1,\ldots)\notin\ell^2$; however, if one restricts the domain of the operator such that given $u\in\ell^2$
$$
Au=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2|u_k|^2<\infty
$$
then it makes sense. So, by changing the domain, we get a bounded linear operator that is also closed. Is this correct?

Comment: I think you mean $$D(A) = \{u:\; \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 |u_k|^2 < \infty\}$$
and $(Au)_k = k u_k$ for $u \in D(A)$.  No, it's not a bounded linear operator on $D(A)$, it's an unbounded closed linear operator.

Comment: Yes! This was my conclusion, but only after analyzing the point spectrum. Can one construct a sequence that converges to a point not belonging to the pre-image? Does this automatically mean that it is not closed?

Comment: "Closed" means the graph is closed in $\ell^2 \times \ell^2$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator

Answer (score 1):

Define $Bu = ((1/k)u_k)$. This operator is bounded, and $Bu \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ for all $u$ with $ABu=u$. And, $BAu=u$ for $u\in\mathcal{D}(A)$. So these operators $A$ and $B$ are inverses. $B$ is closed because it is bounded, which automatically means that the graph of $A$ is closed because it is the transpose of the graph of $B$ in $\ell^{2}\times \ell^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Unbounded operators $A$ acting in a Hilbert space are usually studied through their resolvent $[z-A]^{-1}$, see Kato, Perturbation Theory of Linear Operators and the four volumes of Reed and Simon, Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics. For a useful theory the operator $A$ must be densely defined and closable. The resolvent set consists of those $z$ for which $[z-A]^{-1}$ is a bounded operator, its complement is the spectrum of $A$. The domain of $A$ acting in the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is then precisely the range of $[z-A]^{-1}$ for some $z$ from the resolvent set. This is somewhat different from what you have in mind.

Edit: In case $A$ is a closed, densely defined, operator, $\mathcal{D}(A)$
can be made into a Hilbert space by introducing a suitable norm which is
sometimes referred to as the graph norm. For instance
$$
\parallel f\parallel _{\mathcal{D}(A)}=\parallel (z-A)f\parallel ,\;f\in
\mathcal{D}(A)
$$
for some $z$ from the resolvent set of $A$. Then, although $A$ need not be
bounded on $\mathcal{H}$ $\textbf{it is bounded}$ as a map from $\mathcal{D}(A)
$ into $\mathcal{H}$. However this generally does not have consequences for
the spectral properties of $A$.

On the other hand, the specific $A$ you are considering has a compact
resolvent which implies that  the spectrum of $A$ is discrete and the
eigenvalues have finite multiplicities. But this was already clear.

Comment: Yes, I am well-aware of the resolvent set. I am just curious about if $(D(A),A)$ is bounded and closed. I constructed the domain so that it should be bounded and closed, but then the when analyzing the spectrum I find that the point spectrum consists of all positive integers (which is not bounded, hence it cannot be a bounded operator?). Also, $A$ is symmetric (possibly self-adjoint).

Comment: Please, see my edit.